# Negative reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation, reputation-display

Thinking particularly of new users who get many downvotes for their first question, their calculated reputation should be a negative number, but is displayed as `1`.

Is their reputation *actually* negative but rendered as `1`?
or
is their reputation actually bottom-capped at `1` so for example after a heap of downvotes a single upvote will change their reputation to `2`?

Comment: Because we’re positive people.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Actually that was a stupid question... of course - I've removed it. The initial mechanical questions remain however

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/164376 (Second bullet point under Additionally)